# python telnet tn.read_until() usage

Tags: python, echo, telnet, netcat, telnetlib

What is the right way to extract number from the output of SPCI in device telnet? There are "Measured:Power?", "-5.25031482E+001"(this is what I need to extract), "empty line", "SCPI> ". Is there anything I can do to improve the code to only outputs "-5.25031482E+001"?

Code (I used telnet ip_addr port, and then do tn.write() and tn.read_very_eager() to output the reasult):

```
import csv
from string import split
import sys
import telnetlib


Host = "192.168.1.10"
PORT = 5024
i = open('practice1.csv', 'wb')  
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(Host,PORT)
print "you logged in :)"

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    tn.write("Measure:Power?\n")
    time.sleep(5)
    data = ' '
    #if tn.read_very_eager() != "" :
    if data.find('W') == -1:
        data = tn.read_very_eager()
        print data
```

Result (There are SCPI>, empty line and number, I only want number):

```
x@x:~/Desktop/Keysight_N1914A$ python powermater.py 
you logged in :)
Welcome to A-N1914A-00010 - Agilent Technologies Agilent N1914A (SG56040006) SCPI parser.

SCPI> Measure:Power?

-5.25031482E+001
SCPI> 
-5.25028874E+001
SCPI> 
-5.25132798E+001
SCPI> 
-5.25077163E+001
SCPI> 

-5.24950509E+001
SCPI> 

-5.25008686E+001
SCPI> 
-5.25210976E+001
SCPI> 
-5.25151648E+001
SCPI> 
-5.25099852E+001
SCPI> 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "powermater.py", line 40, in <module>
    time.sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: split output using:
line = data.split('\n')

Comment: I figured out myself, use tn.read_until("-"), the output can be nicely sorted out as SCPI>- and number.